# Error 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getParameterized' on spark cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have scala application running with Spark on local (from IntelliJ IDE) but I have got following error when run my application on spark cluster:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getParameterized(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;[Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken;
at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.query(Database.java:502)
at com.ibm.ursus.repositories.CloudantRepository.read(CloudantRepository.scala:61)
```

My application using `GSON` library version `2.8.2`:

```
"com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [article](https://hadoopsters.com/2019/05/08/how-to-override-a-spark-dependency-in-client-or-cluster-mode/) that points me in the right direction.
So the fix for the issue are the following lines in `spark-submit`:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
 --jars gson-2.8.2.jar \
 --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=gson-2.8.2.jar \
 --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=gson-2.8.2.jar \
```

It adding right library to the on the Spark cluster and adding it to the classpath  before 'inner' Spark library `2.2.4`.